# MySQL query to get codes of countries

Tags: mysql, sql

I am developing an application, in one part of it I get a string as the phone number and I have to return the phone provider of that number, in database I have table prefix with this structure:

```
id , name, code
```

Some data in it is like:

```
(23242, 'UK-Mobile-T Mobile', '447984'),
(23243, 'UK-Mobile-T Mobile', '447985'),
(23244, 'UK-Mobile-T Mobile', '447986'),
(23245, 'UK-Mobile-T Mobile', '447987'),
(23246, 'UK-Mobile-Vodafone', '447407'),
(23247, 'UK-Mobile-Vodafone', '447423'),
```

name is the provider and code is the prefix belongs to that provider
and what I get as input is a phone number just like `447243xxxxx`

Question is this:
how should I create a query to return the UK-Mobile-Vodafone as a result when the above input is given ?

please remember length of this code is not same for every country

Comment: Why should it return *UK-Mobile-Vodafone* for the given input?

Comment: @hjpotter92 because as you can see in the data 447423 is one of the prefix codes that belongs to UK-Vodafone so 447423xxxxx belongs to that provider

Comment: but 447423 and 447243 are different numbers ~_~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may work for you:

```
select t.*
from table t
where '447243xxxxx' like concat(t.code, '%');
```

This assumes, among other things, that only one prefix matches each number.  Otherwise you need to choose among them.

If you need to choose among them, typically you would want the longest matching one:

```
select t.*
from table t
where '447243xxxxx' like concat(t.code, '%')
order by length(t.code) desc
limit 1;
```

And then, if you want to be able to use an index, you don't want to use `concat()` on the `code`.  Instead, extract the first n characters.  This is easy if all have the same length (6) as in your example:

```
select t.*
from table t
where left('447243xxxxx', 6) = t.code;
```

Comment: Thanks for immediate answer I'll try it and make it as the correct answer if it works

Comment: Thanks that was the most suitable answer I've ever get here

Answer (score 0):

Just use the LIKE-operator with GROUP BY:

```
SELECT NAME FROM TBL_TABLENAME WHERE CODE LIKE '447243%' group by NAME;
```

Comment: that simply doesn't work because codes for different countries have different lengths

Comment: The `%` does not care about length.

Comment: and I haven't length of this code for each  country

Comment: @Siavosh Different countries aren't prefaced with 44

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I know that how it helps?